# How can I test celery.crontab schedule executes at expected time?

Tags: python, datetime, celery, cron, timedelta

Current crontab settings here:

```
 crontab(day_of_month=2, hour=2, minute=0)
```

But I can't figure out how this schedule will be correctly executed on code.
Are there any way to test celery crontab schedule?

Comment: Here is a detailed solution, how to check test the schedule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586967/how-to-test-celery-periodic-task-in-django/67597941#67597941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `cron.remaining_estimate(datetime.now())`

Comment: where can we add this line ? I am having trouble finding the file where I should write this to find the remaining estimate.