# Testing Celery Beat

Tags: django, time, celerybeat

i work on a celery beat task within a django project which creates Database entries periodically. I know so beacuse when i set the task up like this :

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery("clock-backend", broker=os.environ.get("RABBITMQ_URL"))

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.conf.beat_schedule = {

    'create_reports_monthly': {
        'task': 'project_celery.tasks.create_reports_monthly',
        'schedule': 10.0,
    },
}
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And start my project it really creates an object every 10 seconds.

But what i really want to do is to set it up to run every first day of a month.

To do so i would change `"schedule": crontab(0, 0, day_of_month="1")`.

Here comes my actual problem : How do i test that this really works ?

And by testing i mean actual (unit)tests.

What I've tried is to work with a package called [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun).
A test with this looks like this :

```
def test_start_of_month_report_creation(self, user_object, contract_object, report_object):
    # set time to the last day of January
    with freeze_time("2019-01-31 23:59:59") as frozen_time:
        # let one second pass
        frozen_time.tick()
        # give the celery task some time
        time.sleep(20)
        # Test Logic to check whether the object was created
        # Example: assert MyModel.objects.count() > 0
```

But this did not work. I suspect that the celery beat does not use the time set via freezgun/python but the real "hardware" clock.

I've also tried setting the Hardwareclock like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193964/set-the-hardware-clock-in-python) but this did not work in my setup.

I'm thankful for any comments, remarks or help on this topic since i'd really like to implement a test for this.

Comment: Unit tests are not for testing 3rd party libraries. You should possibly use a monitoring solution to make sure that celerybeat is running and that the report is being generated

Comment: Well I'd like to see whether my task is executed correctly at the beginning of each month. I do not solely want to test the periodic task feature of celery beat.

Comment: maybe just send yourself an email or log a statement to know that your task ran successfully

Comment: Here is a solution, how to check test the schedule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586967/how-to-test-celery-periodic-task-in-django/67597941#67597941

Comment: @hendrikschneider any chance for writing a current solution as an answer? It would be helpful to test the task's crontab was installed correctly by the project CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE setting.  It doesn't appear that the run_every option is available on tasks anymore

Answer (score 0):

1. Unit tests cannot test third-party libraries.
2. You can set the system log, to keep track.
3. You can check if your task is already on model PeriodicTask. This model defines a single periodic task to be run. It must be associated with a schedule, which defines how often the task should run.